# How to stop FFmpeg from doing anything with the supplied video, other than dumping metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, media, thumbnails

I'm using ffmpeg to extract the embedded thumbnail from a video:

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t cover.webp -i video.mkv
```

The problem is, that ffmpeg complains that at least one output file must be specified.

Adding an output file like `-f raw /dev/null` or similar is unsatisfactory, as ffmpeg still accesses the file, decodes it and then writes it to /dev/null -- something I specifically want to avoid.

Adding the options `-an -vn` also results in an error.

In essence, I want ffmpeg to do nothing else with the video, not even decode it, as all I need is dumping the embedded cover art, which is already accomplished by the `-dump_attachment:t` option.

Is there a way to make ffmpeg not do anything basically? the only thing I could come up with is using `-c copy -f null /dev/null` but that also results in accessing the entire file.

For now, this is what I use:

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t cover.webp -i video.mkv -f ffmetadata /dev/null
```

However that is a pretty bad workaround I suppose.

Comment: Why don’t you use `exiftool` instead? It’s only purposed dealing wit metadata; much better that FFmpeg’s limited functionality as far as metadata goes.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 no idea how to do it with exiftool, tbh

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=3856.msg50970#msg50970) from the official ExifTool forum. It’s tricky but it seems possible. It seems like this command can work as of 2019: `exiftool -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -b -preview:all DIR`. As Phil Harvey (`exiftool` author) syates, “This will extract multiple images from each file if they exist.”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 this still works perfectly. You may want to add `-ext mkv` in front of the directory name <DIR> to process only videofiles, in case there are other files there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add a short output duration.

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t cover.webp -i video.mkv -map 0:a -t 1 -f null -
```

FFmpeg probes each input in a command. This means accessing all streams and decoding a short portion so as to get accurate codec attributes of each stream. The probed data is then buffered and released when the actual processing starts.

Comment: my version with `-f ffmetadata /dev/null` only inspects metadata and is almost instantaneous...

Comment: ffmpeg will probe input irrespective of the output format.